# Scrolling down a scrollView slowly

Tags: android, scrollview

I've tried to use scrollBy and scrollTo, but they scroll too fast. Is there a way I can decide the speed at which the scrollView scrolls?

Comment: I don't know if you can actually set the speed of the scrolling, but you could see if smoothScrollTo(...) meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass in an [Interpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) to adjust the speed.  Subclass the Interpolator class to create whatever function to adjust the speed by.

edit: Hmm, I assumed that there would be an easy way to do this in a ScrollView since it's a constructor argument for a Scroller object.  You might want to just do the scrolling yourself with a Scroller object using whatever interpolation you choose.  I'll try to find more.

Comment: Thanks. What if I create my own scrollView class that extends the interpolator? That way I can just create that class and control the speed that way.

Comment: @cj1098 It would probably be easiest to just copy this code into a custom scrollview class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ScrollView.java  From that you can see they have a private Scroller object which you can then replace with our own version that has an Interpolator added to it.

Comment: Sorry, linked you to an old version, here is the 4.2 version: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/ScrollView.java#ScrollView